# UIPanGestureRecogniser not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I've got this function to handle the dragging of a view:+

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)



    let newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
        recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

    print("the translation x:\(translation.x) & y:\(newCenter.y)")

    if (newCenter.y >= 397 && newCenter.y <= 632) {
        recognizer.view!.center = newCenter


        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }


}
```

The positions are right.
However, the view that I need to move often blocks while I'm dragging, so I need to stop and start dragging it again.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: My code looks like this now, but I still got the problem:

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)


        switch recognizer.state {
            case .Ended:fallthrough
            case .Changed:

                let newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                    recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

                print("the translation x:\(translation.x) & y:\(newCenter.y)")

                if (newCenter.y >= 397 && newCenter.y <= 632) {
                    recognizer.view!.center = newCenter
                    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)}

            default : break }


}
```

Comment: determine state of gesture as end, beginning. it will help.

Comment: `recognizer.state` and then try to add the code @ `.Changed`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Sorry.
@Korpel

Comment: add the following to your code.
`switch recognizer.state
        {
        case .Ended:fallthrough
        case .Changed:
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        default : break
           }`
And remove
`recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)`
Tell me what happens now!Keep in mind that you might have to add all the code you have there inside your `.Changed` state and see if that solved your issue. Probably will do so.

Comment: Edited the post, I still have the problem @Korpel

Comment: i think the sloppiness is due to `recognizer.view!.center = newCenter`

Comment: Can I do it differently? @Korpel

Comment: I don't really know what exactly the logic of the app is so i can't really tell you how to fix a particular problem.Also i noticed this line `recognizer.view!.center = newCenter` let me tell you that on iOS development the values in the y axis are negative so perhaps you should change the values to negative. The origin is 0.0 and it moves downwards to negative y values.

Comment: Actually the movement is upward, since the initial position of the view is on the bottom of the screen @Korpel

Comment: `recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y` this isn't from the bottom and also `centre` is from the `frame` and NOT from the `bounds`.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know the other parts of your code, this is a section assuming what yours might and should look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// Gesture function
func panAround(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    switch recognizer.state {
    ...
    case .Changed:
        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(yourView)
        let newCenter = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2,
                recognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

        print("the translation x:\(translation.x) & y:\(newCenter.y)")

        if (newCenter.y >= 397 && newCenter.y <= 632) {
            recognizer.view!.center = newCenter

            // Updating the UI whenever there is a "small change"
            updateUI()

            recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
        }
    ...
    }
}

private func updateUI() {
    yourView.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

NOTE: The code above WILL NOT work directly by copy and pasting, I am merely pointing out where you can make adjustments.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what is happening to the view you wish to move? Is it simply not moving at all or is it just moving a few pixels and stops so you have to keep on "swiping" to move it?

Comment: Yeah the second one. It moves to the right places, but I (sometimes) I need to swipe several time to get to the point.

Comment: Are you calling `.setNeedsDisplay` every time your centre changes?

Comment: I have edited my answer due to the understanding of your question, please check.

Comment: Doesn't work... Actually I'm detecting this problem only near the end of the movement, when the view is almost at his top (or bottom) height.